# How do I get a run duration in minutes for each individual step in a single job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, jobs

The `Run_Duration` in `sysjobhistory` of the complete job. Is there a way to get this? `[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobactivity]` only has the last step.

Comment: Look at `last_run_duration` in [`sysjobsteps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobsteps-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 5):

This should get you started...

```
select 
    jobs.name
    ,jobs.description
    ,steps.step_id
    ,steps.step_name
    ,steps.last_run_outcome
    ,last_run_time = stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(steps.last_run_time as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':')
    ,last_run_duration = stuff(stuff(right('00000' + cast(steps.last_run_duration as varchar),6),3,0,':'),6,0,':')
from [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] jobs
inner join [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] steps on
steps.job_id = jobs.job_id
order by jobs.job_id, steps.step_id
```

Comment: In this case you use [sysjobsteps] where I have my ALL data stored in [sysjobHistory]

Answer (score 2):

In this case you use [sysjobsteps] where I have my ALL data stored in [sysjobHistory] This below gives duration in seconds though. My suggestion:

`SELECT top 1000 j.name as JobName, step_id, jh.step_name StepName, 
CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(STR(jh.run_date,8, 0) AS dateTIME), 112) as RunDate, 
STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( jh.run_time AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') RunTime, 
STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( jh.run_duration AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') RunDuration, 
case jh.run_status when 0 then 'failed' 
when 1 then 'Succeded' 
when 2 then 'Retry' 
when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
when 4 then 'In Progress' 
end as ExecutionStatus, 
FROM sysjobhistory jh inner join sysjobs j
ON j.job_id = jh.job_id
ORDER BY j.name, jh.run_date, jh.run_time`

Answer (score 2):

Thnaks, it has helped a lot. There is a small bug as the Duration is not in Seconds it is in HHMMSS

I have fix it this way:

```
SELECT x.executable_name
, x.start_time
, x.end_time AS end_time
, datediff(minute, x.start_time, x.end_time) AS Duration
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT --TOP 100 PERCENT 
    cast([sJOB].[job_id] AS VARCHAR(max)) AS execution_id
    , [sJSTP].[step_name] AS executable_name
    , [sJOB].[name] AS package_name
    , CASE [sJSTP].[run_date]
        WHEN 0
            THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(CAST([sJSTP].[run_date] AS CHAR(8)) + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJSTP].[run_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)
        END AS start_time
    , dateadd(ss, --run_duration

  substring(cast(100000000 + [sJSTP].run_duration AS NVARCHAR), 2, 4) * 60*60 -- Hours
+ substring(cast(100000000 + [sJSTP].run_duration AS NVARCHAR), 6, 2) * 60 -- Minutes
+ substring(cast(100000000 + [sJSTP].run_duration AS NVARCHAR), 8, 2)  -- Seconds

    , CASE [sJSTP].[run_date]
            WHEN 0
                THEN NULL
            ELSE CAST(CAST([sJSTP].[run_date] AS CHAR(8)) + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJSTP].[run_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)
            END) end_time
    --    , [sJSTP].[run_duration] [looptijd in minuten]
    , CASE [sJSTP].[run_status]
        WHEN 0
            THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'Success'
        WHEN 2
            THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN 3
            THEN 'Cancelled'
        WHEN 5
            THEN 'Unknown'
        END AS execution_result_description
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] AS [sJSTP]
INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [sJOB]
    ON [sJSTP].[job_id] = [sJOB].[job_id]
INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] steps
    ON [sJSTP].[job_id] = [steps].[job_id]
WHERE [sJSTP].[run_date] <> 0
    AND CASE [sJSTP].[run_date]
        WHEN 0
            THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(CAST([sJSTP].[run_date] AS CHAR(8)) + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJSTP].[run_time] AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)
        END BETWEEN dateadd(day, - 20, getdate())
        AND getdate()
    AND [sJSTP].[step_name] NOT IN ('(Job outcome)')
    AND [sJOB].name = '<JOB Name>'
    AND [sJSTP].[step_name] = '<Step Name>'
    --order by start_time desc
) x
ORDER BY start_time DESC
```